# Go command not found while running code deploy hook

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-code-deploy

Hello I'm trying to create a CodeDeploy deployment for my golang application. I have an autoscaling group that uses a AMI I created that has all the libs I need installed. When I try to run CodeDeploy it exists with an error in my `after_install`:

```
LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall
Script - scripts/after_install.sh
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/a65d9a2e-fddd-471c-8ea1-c018792d00bd/d-4IKP3PP4Y/deployment-archive/scripts/after_install.sh: 
line 4: go: command not found
```

I know go is installed on the server I can verify by sshing into the server and running the go command. Initially I had my `after_install` hook run as root so that's why I thought it complained about go not being installed.

I updated it to run as `ubuntu` here is the appspec file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: ./
    destination: ./home/ubuntu/code
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: ubuntu
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/application_start.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: root
```

But I still get the error of go command not found. I SSH into the server as `ubuntu` user and I can clearly see go is installed.

I took it one step further and ran the `after_install.sh` file and it worked with no errors. What am I doing wrong here?

Just for the extra curious here is my `after_install.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ubuntu/code/vibeify/cmd/vibeify
go build
```

Comment: Where is go installed? Is that path configured for the ubuntu user? Add 'echo $PATH' to the script and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `go` command without the full installation path only in the interactive shell, check `$HOME/.bashrc`.

It may depends on OS default settings, but some OS default bashrc file includes scripts that does not load profile in non-interactive shell.

```sh
# open $HOME/.bashrc file
# and comment out these lines
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: Environment variables like PATH should be in a profile file, not an rc file. There’s a reason they’re not loaded.